# Using fancyvrb insid newenvironment together with other packages

Tags: environments, fancyvrb

I've found some examples on how to use the fancyvrb package inside a `\newenvironment` command. But they don't quite cover what I want to do. Here is the code I tried to make work:

```
\newenvironment{example}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\tiny]}
{\end{BVerbatim}}

\newenvironment{Example}
{\begin{mdframed}[...]\begin{center}\begin{example}}
{\end{example}\end{center}\end{mdframed}}
```

So I want a `BVerbatim` environment inside a centered frame.
The `example` environment works fine but it can't get the centered frame part to work. The error I get is:

```
File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare also `Example` as verbatim:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,mdframed}

\newenvironment{example}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\tiny]}
{\end{BVerbatim}}

\newenvironment{Example}
{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{mdframed}\begin{center}\begin{example}}
{\end{example}\end{center}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Something
here
\end{example}

\begin{Example}
Something
here
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image]